# Can't watch and download video from iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, mac, video, itunes-u

I am experiencing a problem while trying to watch an iOS development course in iTunes on macOS. You can find the course here:

https://itunes.apple.com/ru/course/developing-ios-10-apps-with-swift/id1198467120?l=en

If I try to click the play button and watch videos 1 to 6, iTunes just does nothing. It seems to ignore my action. If I try to download the videos, it looks like they are downloading, but they turn out to have formatting problems.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

If I try to open this video I get this message:

```
The movie could not be opened.
An invalid public movie atom was found in the movie.
```

or this:

```
The movie could not be opened.
The file is not a movie file.
```

But interestingly, if I try watch online or download video from the 6th one to the last one they work properly. I can watch them as well as download them.

What is the issue here? What am I doing wrong?

If I skip something feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem with the Stanford iOS 10 course on iTunes for Mac. I eventually gave up and downloaded the videos on iTunes for Windows.

However, I more recently fixed the problem by reinstalling macOS. You can do this by holding <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on startup, clicking on "Reinstall macOS" or "Reinstall OS X", and following the prompts.

Note that this will **not** destroy any of your files or programs. It simply reinstalls the system applications, but any settings, files, or applications that you have on your computer should not be changed.

(You may consider making a backup first.)

Answer (score 0):

If someone will looking for the resources that I looked for, so there is a link to youtube channel

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsdOYqsUTqTRetMWwuUBxxg

Comment: This looks like a link to a copy of the Stanford courses you were trying to watch.  It doesn't appear to resolve your problem, though, so is really an answer?  Also, these courses are copyrighted by Stanford so I doubt they'll stay on youtube for much longer.

Comment: Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. If you have more info to add to your question, you can do this by using the _edit_ link below your question. Doing so will improve your chances of getting a good answer, as the whole issue is explained together in the one spot.